# Leaflet: Force a map redraw from Layer extension

Tags: javascript, geospatial, leaflet

I am currently developing an extension to the L.TileLayer class, and from within the initialize method I would like to call a redraw on the map.  My code looks like this:

```
L.TileLayer.NewLayerType = L.TypeLayer.extend({
    _newLayerType: null,
    initialize: function(file, options) {
        var foo = new Foo(file, this, function(scope) {
            ...
            scope.redraw();
        });
        L.Utils.setOptions(this, options);
    },
    ...
});
```

The problem is, the scope.redraw() call does not work, nor does any other way of refreshing the map work outside of calling scope._map.zoomIn() and scope._map.zoomOut() immediately after.  Is the redraw not working because the scope is a layer extension?  What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering.... `TypeLayer`?